# Can you use Firebase cloud messaging instead of poling to update an alert counter

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have a web Vue project that has an alert counter in the nav bar. We want the counter to update when a new alert comes through. Currently we are hitting the server every 15sec to see it has updated, but we would like the server to tell the client when to update.

Is it possible to use Firebase cloud messaging to do this **without having to ask the user to allow push notifications**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get past the user accepting push notifications from the site. You need to make it clear to the user that if they want realtime notification they need to accept push notification.